# How to Create Swf Slide Show

Tags: flash, slideshow, fireworks

Anyone know how to do so? Something like http://apartemenpavilion.com/images/flash/news.swf

I used fireworks and what I got is something like http://apartemenpavilion.com/images/flash/newsimage/player_white.swf Looks like fireworks can't make simpler slide show.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flash instead of Fireworks.
I have not try these tutorials myself, but it may be a starting point for you:

http://layersmagazine.com/flash-slideshow-image-gallery.html

http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/128/46/

Comment: Thanks also, I'll try after above. :-{)

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.thetechlabs.com/tutorials/files/flash/rnunlist/slideshow/slideshow.html and get all the info and fla's here: http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-tutorials/xml/create-a-as3-slideshow-with-xml/

Comment: Thank you very much! let me try then :-{)